# Нестабильная и долгая загрузка странички Django + Apache + Windows по внешней ссылке

Tags: python, django, apache

Есть страничка сайта, которая грузится через localhost мгновенно, а если обращаться по имени сервера или через доменное имя, то загрузка странички происходит то быстро, то зависает на несколько минут, при этом если в то же время загружать локально то все ок.

Примеры:

[image: пример загрузки через localhost]

[image: пример загрузки через доменное имя]

```
httpd.conf apache
LoadFile "c:/python37/python37.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/python37/Lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/python37"

WSGIScriptAlias / "c:/django_project/kors/kors/wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonPath "c:/python37;C:/django_project/kors/"
WSGIPassAuthorization On

<Directory "c:/django_project/kors/kors/">
    <Files "wsgi.py"> 
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /static "C:/django_project/kors/kors/static"
<Directory "C:/django_project/kors/kors/static">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /media "C:/django_project/kors/kors/static/media"
<Directory "C:/django_project/kors/kors/static/media">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Брэндмауер отключен.

error.log Apache

```
[Tue Apr 20 08:39:02.509160 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6672:tid 680] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
Exception ignored in: <function BaseEventLoop.__del__ at 0x0000000002BE1F78>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 625, in __del__
NameError: name 'ResourceWarning' is not defined
[Tue Apr 20 08:39:02.689152 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1316:tid 648] AH00430: Parent: Child process exited successfully.
[Tue Apr 20 08:40:59.184983 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2528:tid 536] AH00455: Apache/2.4.2 (Win64) mod_wsgi/4.7.1 Python/3.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Apr 20 08:40:59.185976 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2528:tid 536] AH00456: Server built: May 11 2012 20:42:30
[Tue Apr 20 08:40:59.185976 2021] [core:notice] [pid 2528:tid 536] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Apache24 -f C:\\Apache24\\conf\\httpd.conf -d C:\\Apache24\\.'
[Tue Apr 20 08:40:59.186983 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2528:tid 536] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6808
[Tue Apr 20 08:40:59.812930 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6808:tid 676] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

upd.
[image: Загрузка ресурсов]

upd 1.
[image: загрузка main.css]

Comment: Добавил в пост информацию по загрузке. с main.css не могу показать так как сейчас загружается за 67ms. Со статикой как таковой проблем ранее не замечал, такое ощущение что зависает при связи с view.py хотя там поиск в БД из 6 записей.

Comment: хотя вот получилось выложить скрин с загрузкой main.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем после долгих разборов, чтения логов и поиска какой то закономерности принял решение все снести и поставить заново но уже на всех свежих версиях.
| Было| Стало  |
| --------- | -------------- |
| python 3.7 разрядность хз забыл посмотреть   | python 3.9 64x         |
| mod_wsgi/4.7.1 Python/3.7 | mod_wsgi/4.7.1 Python/3.9          |
| Apache/2.4.2 (Win64)|Apache/2.4.46 (Win64)|
|PostgreSQL 10 |PostgreSQL 13 (Win64) |

В итоге пока проблем не наблюдается в течении дня проблемы озвученной ранее не встречалось и в целом возможно при прошлой настройке допускаю что возможно где то ошибся в разрядности python или еще чего то.

Вопрос свой не удаляю вдруг кому то поможет или предостережет.